# Parsing Buffer C - Advance buffer past whitespace, store word

Tags: c++, string

It's been awhile since I worked with the standard C library's string parsing code (sprintf, atoi, etc).

My specific, current need is as follows:

```
advance_buf( const char*& buf, const char* removed_chars, int size );
```

It should advance the `buf` pointer to beyond the group of whitespace and copy the removed characters into `removed_chars` ... The `size` is to keep things safe.

Example before and after, state of `buf` and `removed_chars`:

- Before: `buf`: "123 456  789", `removed_chars`: (empty or garbage).
- After: `buf`: "456  789", `removed_chars`: "123".

I'm also interested in a succinct resource for functions of this sort.

Comment: You'll need to declare that `const char **buf`. There are no references in C. It really has been a while, hasn't it?

Comment: If this is C, don't confuse the issue by introducing C++ references.

Comment: C++'s syntax made it more clear what I was interested in, at least to me. A char** is an ultimately ambiguous symbol.

Comment: If you want C++ syntax, this should be tagged as C++.

Comment: I don't care about the syntax of the function. The above was the easiest, clearest way for me to describe the functionality I desire. I'm hoping to learn 1. What the standard way of doing this would be in C and 2. A good resource for finding functions like this.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like *strtok()* and friends can do the job you want.

Answer (score 1):

This should be trivial:

```
const char * advance_buf(const char *buf, char *removed_chars, size_t size)
{
  /* Copy characters until whitespace found or buffer space runs out. */
  while(!isspace(*buf) && --size > 0)
    *removed_chars++ = *buf++;
  *removed_chars = '\0';

  /* Remove separating whitespace. */
  while(isspace(*buf))
    buf++;
  return buf;
}
```

I changed the signature a bit, to return the updated `buf` pointer.

Comment: I'm aware that the implementation is trivial, but I would prefer to use a standard c solution, if one exists.

Comment: isblank() is C99-only, so isspace() would be a safer choice

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
#define SPACE " \t"

const char *advance_buf(const char *buf, char *removed_chars, int size)
{
    buf += sprintf(removed_chars, "%.*s", min(size - 1, strcspn(buf, SPACE)), buf);
    return buf + strspn(buf, SPACE);
}
```

Note: if `removed_chars` fills up, the excess characters will *not* be removed from `buf`.

```
const char *buf = "123 456789 X"
char removed_chars[5];

// Before: buf: "123 456789 X", removed_chars: (empty).
buf = advance_buf(buf, removed_chars, sizeof (removed_chars));
// After: buf: "456789 X", removed_chars: "123".
buf = advance_buf(buf, removed_chars, sizeof (removed_chars));
// After: buf: "89 X", removed_chars: "4567".
```

Note 2: Although the `sprintf` call is safe because the `"%.*s"` guards against buffer overflow, some modern compilers generate warnings for *any* use of `sprintf()` and some company coding standards prohibit it.  If so then it should trivial to substitute `snprintf` or `sprintf_s`.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend having a look at the `strspn()` and `strcspn()` functions. The following will tell you how many characters there are until the next chunk of whitespace:

```
strcspn(string, " \t");
```

And the following will tell you how long a chunk of whitespace is:

```
strspn(string, " \t");
```

You can use those numbers to do this task fairly easily, and probably thread-safely if you need.